# MLCP export : is it possible to change the name of zip files created by mlcp export

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

The zip files created by export have filenames of the form "timestamp-seqnum.zip" like : 20210630144412+0530-000000-XML.zip
We want to export all the documents from MarkLogic database and then store it on filesystem.
Is there a way to modify name of the zip let say something like: set1.zip,set2.zip?
Also,the documents within zip take the full URI present in database like : "urn:ab:people:123456"
Is there a way to format that URI: like we want only last part[123456] but not the full URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MLCP has only limited features to influence what you export. An MLCP transform might allow adjusting contents and uri while exporting, but zip file names are chosen by MLCP, as it generates chunks automatically.

It may be worth looking into [Corb2](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/corb/). If not, just add some scripting on top of MLCP to rename files to your liking.

HTH!